# Phantomjs' selenium Ajax code not loaded

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I just discovered Selenium and I'm trying to learn how to use it with PhantomJS. The first example I've found was about getting a list of links from booking.com.
I tried running it with PhantomJS without luck. Firefox runs it well. The code in java looks like this:

```
private void start() {
    Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,                       "D:\\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
    //WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.booking.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("destination")).sendKeys("Berlin");
    //saveSShot(driver, "sel1.png");
    long timeOut = 5000;
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeOut;

    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {

        if (String.valueOf(
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                        .executeScript("return document.readyState"))
                .equals("complete")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    //saveSShot(driver, "sel2.png");
    try {
        //writeFile(driver, "output1.txt");
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("ul.ui-autocomplete li a"))).click();
        //writeFile(driver, "output2a.txt");
        //saveSShot(driver, "sel3.png");
        driver.findElement(By.name("idf")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.className("b-searchbox-button")).submit();

        List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By
                .cssSelector("a.hotel_name_link"));
        for (WebElement webElement : list) {
            System.out.println(webElement.getText());
        }
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        //writeFile(driver, "output.txt");
    }
}
```

Note the two declarations of driver. If I use Firefox, the WebDriverWait works. On PhantomJS it gives an error with WebDriverWait (Element not found  :262 in error)

I have added all code. You can paste it in a new project, add the class and includes and you'll see how it (not) work. The two commented method saveSShot and writeFile must be written. I used them for debugging purposes. What I see on the second screenshot is that "Berlin" is in fact written, but the ajax dropdown isn't there. With Firefox it appears.

Comment: Have you taken a screenshot to see if you're on the correct page? Have you printed the page source to see if the element exists?

Comment: @mobinoob I have some similar issue when changing a selection that should trigger an ajax call, but does not. The error only occurs with PhantomJS not with Firefox. When we inspected the issue with screenshots before and after the selectByValue, it looked like the selection did not occur. You should check screenshots and source as  Artjom B. suggested

Comment: @ArtjomB. I did check the source after the SendKeys and I didn't see any <LI>. I didn't find "Berlin" inside the textbox as well, but that I shouldn't see,right? I will try with screenshots

Comment: @JeskoR. Have you discovered why? I might use ByClassname instead of By.id and try again

Comment: @JeskoR. By.Id works perfectly. I see "Berlin" on the screenshot. You can test my code if you wish. it's all there now.

Comment: @mobinoob I would think that the WebDriverWait does the trick for you. However, in my situation I try to deal with PageObjects that define the elements beforehand and I receive a StaleElementReferenceException when I try to wait, as unfortunately the DOM tree gets deleted and rebuild for this portion of the code.

Comment: @JeskoR.It is definitely PhantomJs. I don't see any dropdown on the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with ghostDriver: this is a generic WebDriver usage case. You need to define such a scenario yourself, most probably by registering some JS in the page to do the check for you, and use the driver to pick up the result. You should provide a mechanism that waits for this element to be *displayed* and *enabled*. Waiting for the page's ready-state. Such simple solution can do the trick:

```
long timeOut = 5000;
long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeOut;

    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {

        if (String.valueOf(
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                        .executeScript("return document.readyState"))
                .equals("complete")) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

I've used the ghostDriver for rich content (gaming sites) and it worked pretty well with all the AJAX.

I did some research and this is what I find working too:

```
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    wait.Until(d => (bool)(d as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
```

Here is [an article](http://automationrhapsody.com/efficient-waiting-for-ajax-call-data-loading-with-selenium-webdriver/) that can help you if you decide to proceed with the JS code.

Comment: The exception is with the WebDriverWait, not with the findElement you have shown. Also it can't be generic, since it works with Firefox but not with PhantomJS. I'll try your wait loop before the WebDriverWait anyway.

Comment: The wait loop doesn't affect it. It immediately continues. Screenshots show that the pulldown menu doesn't appear at all.

Comment: @ekostadinov I tried to work with it quite a bit, but the document ready state would not change when an ajax call was in progress. I would assume that would be different if the page got reloaded, but that would defeat the purpose of the ajax call in the first place. Would you mind giving a more complete example?

Comment: Like I said this is the solution that works in my case. I've done some try outs with the new code snippet - see my updated answer.

Comment: @ekostadinov I've converted your code to java, but still no luck. Phantomjs is definitely doesn't use Ajax, otherwise the screenshot would have been different on my test (with our without your code)

Comment: @mobinoob I guess that using headless does not work completely properly with Ajax application so many sync issues comes with this. Be sure to give Phantom.js (under the hood) enough time to complete the ajax calls.  It allows you to wait asynchronously for certain conditions to be met, and when it's met, it finally unblocked the script to continue 
processing. You can evaluate many conditions using the waits.

Comment: @ekostadinov I tried with a thread.sleep(15000) as well, with no luck.